# Python newest file in a directory

Tags: python, file, directory, listdir

I am working on a script where I am trying to list the newest file ending with .xls. It should be easy, but I am receiving some errors.

Code:

```
for file in os.listdir('E:\\Downloads'):
    if file.endswith(".xls"):
        print "",file
        newest = max(file , key = os.path.getctime)
        print "Recently modified Docs",newest
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\sele.py", line 49, in <module>
    newest = max(file , key = os.path.getctime)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\genericpath.py", line 72, in getctime
    return os.stat(filename).st_ctime
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'u'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
newest = max(file , key = os.path.getctime)
```

This is iterating over the characters in your filename instead of your list of files.

You are doing something like `max("usdfdsf.xls", key = os.path.getctime)`instead of `max(["usdfdsf.xls", ...], key = os.path.getctime)`

You probably want something like

```
files = [x for x in os.listdir('E:\\Downloads') if x.endswith(".xls")]
newest = max(files , key = os.path.getctime)
print "Recently modified Docs",newest
```

You may want to also improve the script so that it works if you're not in the Downloads directory:

```
files = [os.path.join('E:\\Downloads', x) for x in os.listdir('E:\\Downloads') if x.endswith(".xls")]
```

Comment: Still going me errors: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\sele.py", line 47, in <module>
    newest = max(files , key = os.path.getctime)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\genericpath.py", line 72, in getctime
    return os.stat(filename).st_ctime
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'usage01.12.2015_31.12.2015(1).xls'`

Comment: Updated answer. It's because you aren't running it from the Downloads directory so `getcttime` only looks in the current directory and can't find the file.

Comment: That worked. Now I am getting `E:\Downloads\usage01.12.2015_31.12.2015(3).xls`. How can I only get the filename without the path ?

Comment: Use `os.path.basename` on your final output https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename

Answer (score 3):

You can use `glob` to get a list of `xls` files.

```
import os
import glob

files = glob.glob('E:\\Downloads\\*.xls')

print("Recently modified Docs", max(files , key=os.path.getctime))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer the more up-to-date pathlib solution, here it is:

```py
from pathlib import Path

XLSX_DIR = Path('../../somedir/')
XLSX_PATTERN = r'someprefix*.xlsx'

latest_file = max(XLSX_DIR.glob(XLSX_PATTERN), key=lambda f: f.stat().st_ctime)
```

Comment: it is also helpful to add an `default=None` option, in case the glob returns an empty generator