# Finding latest file in a folder using python

Tags: python

I've searched for an answer for this but the answers still gave me `an error message` and I wasn't allowed to ask there because I had to make a new question. So here it goes...

I need my python script to use the latest file in a folder.

I tried several things, currently the piece of code looks like this:

```
list_of_files = glob.glob('/my/path/*.csv')
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getmtime)
```

But the code fails with the following comment:

`ValueError: max()` arg is an empty sequence

Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: Error is telling you that your `list_of_files` is empty you may need to provide a full path or change the working directory first

Comment: Which Python version are you using? And which OS?  `max` (and `min`) in Python 3 has a way of handling empty lists. But it's cleaner to make sure `list_of_files` isn't empty before you pass it to `max`.

Comment: Thank you, explaining the error message alone was very helpful. It gives me a clue where to fix things.

I'm using python 3.6. The list of files shouldn't be empty and the path is right for as far as I can tell, I'll have to go and figure out why it returns an empty list of files. Thanks!

Comment: print out that variable before preforming `max` to see if it is what you expect it to be

Comment: Another thing: Shouldn't the max be inside: `key=max(os.path.getmtime)`

Comment: If you're on Linux (or other Unix-like system) then '/my/path/' is an absolute path, i.e., '/my' is a directory in the root of the filesystem, it's not relative to the current directory. So make sure that you're globbing the path that you actually want.

Comment: @AntonvBR No, that would try to make a key from the `max` of each individual timestamp, which doesn't make a lot of sense, and `max` raises `TypeError` if you try to get the maximum of a number rather than an iterable.

Comment: The problem solved here is duplicate e.g. to https://stackoverflow.com/a/70404383/1615108

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be ok if the list is not empty, but it seems to be. So first check if the list isn't empty by printing it or something similar.

I tested this code and it worked fine:

```
import os
import glob

mypath = "C:/Users/<Your username>/Downloads/*.*"

print(min(glob.glob(mypath), key=os.path.getmtime)) 
print(max(glob.glob(mypath), key=os.path.getmtime))
```

Answer (score 0):

`glob.glob` has a limitation of not matching the files that start with a `.`

So, if you want to match these files, this is what you should do - (assume a directory having `.picture.png` in it)

```
import glob
glob.glob('.p*') #assuming you're already in the directory
```

Also, it would be an ideal way to check the number of files present in the directory, before operating on them.